# innerHTML VS innerTEXT

Tags: javascript, html

Qual a diferença entre usar o **innerHTML** e o **innerText** em Javascript? Se eu quero mudar o conteúdo do **TEXT_NODE**, qual devo usar?
Por exemplo:

```
<p id="p1">I also wrote a book! Read it
    <a href="http://eloquentjavascript.net">here</a>.
</p>
```

Se eu quero mudar o texto do parágrafo acima, eu usaria desta forma:

```
var p = document.getElementById("p1");
p.innerHTML="Texto Qualquer";
```

ou desta? :

```
var p = document.getElementById("p1");
p.innerText="Texto Qualquer";
```

Tem alguma diferença? Visualmente eu vi que os dois fazem a mesma coisa.

Comment: O problema é que usando um ou outro o link `<a>` vai embora.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

O `innerText` altera o conteúdo de um elemento de sua página (DOM) com o conteúdo tratado apenas como texto. Por exemplo:

```
document.getElementById('Teste').innerText = '<b>teste</b>'
```

Irá exibir:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já o `innerHTML` altera o conteúdo de um elemento com o conteúdo tratado como HTML.

Por exemplo, este código:

```
document.getElementById('Teste').innerHTML = '<b>teste</b>'
```

Será exibido dessa maneira:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Criei um código no jsFiddle para você poder perceber melhor a diferença entre ambos.

https://jsfiddle.net/brunossn/xpvt214o/803018/

Answer (score 7):

O `innerText` pode ser entendindo como:

> uma propriedade que representa o conteúdo textual "renderizado" de
>   um nó e seus descendentes. Usada como getter, retorna de maneira
>   aproximada o texto que o usuário obteria caso tivesse selecionado o
>   conteúdo e copiado para a área de transferência

Já o `innerHTML`:

> define ou obtém a sintaxe HTML descrevendo os elementos descendentes.

Logo, em palavras simples, o `innerText` recupera e define o conteúdo da tag como texto simples, enquanto `innerHTML` recupera e define o conteúdo em formato HTML.

Veja um exemplo onde pegamos o conteúdo HTML da `<div id"innerHTML">`:

```js
let innerHTML = document.getElementById('innerHTML').innerHTML;
console.log(innerHTML);
```

```html
<div id="innerHTML">Texto <span>Mais texto</span></div>
```

Agora veja esse outro exemplo com `innerText`, onde só pegamos o texto, sem a tag `span`, diferentemente do primeiro exemplo:

```js
let innerText = document.getElementById('innerText').innerText;
console.log(innerText);
```

```html
<div id="innerText">Texto <span>Mais texto</span></div>
```

Pegando um gancho no seu exemplo da pergunta, caso queira trocar, por um exemplo, o texto de um link poderia usar o `innerText`. Veja:

```js
var p = document.getElementById("link");
p.innerText="Texto Qualquer";
```

```html
<p id="p1">I also wrote a book! Read it
    <a id="link" href="http://eloquentjavascript.net">here</a>.
</p>
```

Caso você quisesse trocar o conteúdo HTML de uma `div`, ou até mesmo trocar o link de um certo elemento o poderia fazer com o `innerHTML`.

```js
var p = document.getElementById("p1");
p.innerHTML='<a href="https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/329975/innerhtml-vs-innertext">Trocamos o link</a>';
```

```html
<p id="p1">I also wrote a book! Read it
    .
</p>
```

**Referências:**

- [MDN innerText](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Node/innerText)
- [MDN innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)

Answer (score 5):

O `innerText` funciona de forma semelhante ao `textContent`. O `innerHTML` pode adicionar ou pegar elementos `HTML`, já com o `innerText` isso não é possivel, ele pode apenas atribuir um texto ou pegar o texto de determinado elemento.

Answer (score 0):

Neste caso é possível fazer a junção de dois parágrafos, usando o innertext ou o iner HTML? Eu estou tentanto fazer isso e não  estou conseguindo.

function juntarMostrar() {

```
    let texto = document.getElementById("paragrafo1").innerHTML;

    let texto2 = document.getElementsByClassName("area1")[0].innerHTML;

    let juntar = document.querySelectorAll('section'). innerHTML;

    juntar.innerHTML = `${('paragrafo1')} + ${("area1")[0]}`;       
 
    }
```

Comment: Isto não responde realmente à pergunta. Se você tiver uma pergunta diferente, pode fazê-la clicando em [Fazer pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Você também pode [adicionar uma gratificação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) para chamar mais atenção a esta pergunta quando tiver [pontos de reputação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) suficientes. - [Da Revisão](/review/late-answers/380249)