# Como junto textos numa TextArea com Js?

Tags: javascript, html5, loop

Estou tentando fazer uma tabuada, onde o resultado seria mostrado numa textarea já existente no HTML.
Estou usando o innerText para inserir o texto nessa textarea, só que o texto está sendo substituído e só é apresentado o ultimo resultado.

```js
function tabuada() {
    var tabNum = Number(document.getElementById('txtNum').value)
    var mulMin = Number(document.getElementById('mulMin').value)
    var mulMax = Number(document.getElementById('mulMax').value)
    var Tab = document.getElementById('resTab')
    var spcMsg = document.getElementById('msg')


    if (mulMin > mulMax) {
        window.alert('[ERRO] O ultimo multiplicador deve ser maior que o primeiro.')
        spcMsg.innerHTML = 'Preencha novamente os campos.'
    } else if (mulMin < mulMax) {
        for (var cont = mulMin; cont <= mulMax; cont++) {
            
            var resTab = (tabNum * cont)
            Tab.innerText += `${tabNum}x${cont}=${resTab}`
        }

    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Tabuada</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="tabuada.css">
</head>

<body>
    <header id=cabeçalho>
        <h1>Tabuada Online</h1>
    </header>

    <section id="princ">
        <p id="textTab">Digite abaixo o numero do qual você deseja obter a tabuada:</p>
        <div id="div1">
            <p>
                Número: <input type="number" name="txtNum" id="txtNum" />
                X <input type="number" id="mulMin"> até <input type="number" id="mulMax">
                <button onclick="tabuada()" id="botao">obter tabuada</button>
            </p>

        </div>


        <div class="div2">
            <textarea name="resTab" id="resTab" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>

            <aside id="msg">
                <p></p>

            </aside>
        </div>


    </section>
    <script src="tabuada.js">

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Já fiz algo muito parecido com o innerHTML em outro programa, a diferença é que os resultados eram apresentados na mesma linha. O innerText age da mesma forma que o innerHTML, apesar de um inserir apenas texto e o outro as tags? É característica do innerHTML escrever tudo na mesma linha e por isso o texto é substituido? Ou teria que ter algo no código que fizesse essa quebra de linha?

Desde já agradeço a ajuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- [Essa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/329975/innerhtml-vs-innertext) explica a diferenca entre o `innerHTML` e o `innerText`.
- Na sua situacao, acho que voce deveria usar `value` em vez de `innerText`, pois o `textarea` tem comportamento de input.
- Para quebrar a linha voce pode simplesmente adicionar um `\n` no seu resultado e fazer um `reset` do valor do `textarea` sempre que o usuario for clicar no botao `obter tabuada`. Ficaria assim o codigo:

```js
function tabuada() {
        var tabNum = Number(document.getElementById('txtNum').value);
        var mulMin = Number(document.getElementById('mulMin').value);
        var mulMax = Number(document.getElementById('mulMax').value);
        var Tab = document.getElementById('resTab');
        var spcMsg = document.getElementById('msg');

        if (mulMin > mulMax) {
          window.alert(
            '[ERRO] O ultimo multiplicador deve ser maior que o primeiro.',
          );
          spcMsg.innerHTML = 'Preencha novamente os campos.';
        } else if (mulMin < mulMax) {
          Tab.value = ''; // faz o reset dos valores.
          for (var cont = mulMin; cont <= mulMax; cont++) {
            var resTab = tabNum * cont;
            Tab.value += `${tabNum}x${cont}=${resTab}\n`; // adiciona quebra de linha com o `\n` no final
          }
        }
      }
```

Acho que e isso. Espero ter ajudado.