# Como projetar o valor que é inserido em um input no conteúdo de outro elemento?

Tags: javascript

estou tentando reproduzir em tempo real oque a pessoa digitou em uma textarea para um paragrafo, um exemplo seria o proprio sistema de perguntas e respostas desse site, eu digito algo e automaticamente é reproduzido em baixo.

eu tentei de varios jeitos só que quando eu digito algo ex: 't', e digito outra tecla o JV ele exclui  o 't' e subtitui pela tecla que digitei.

To fazendo o site com JV,HTML e CSS para conhecer mais o JV só que fiquei preso nisso!

```
<script>

    function tecla(){
        let paragrafo = document.getElementById('p')
        paragrafo.innerHTML = event.keyCode;
        console.log(event.keyCode);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Você está fazendo `paragrafo.innerHTML = ...`, sempre sobrescrevendo o valor anterior. Ao invés disso, busque concatenar os conteúdos.

Comment: [KeyboardEvent.keyCode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode) foi depreciado e Veja [innerHTML VS innerTEXT](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/329975/innerhtml-vs-innertext)

Answer (score 1):

### O problema ocorre devido ao operador atual utilizado..

Antes de mais nada sugiro que veja os [Operadores de atribuição](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#operador_atribuicao), pois você está "atribuindo" o valor e não "somando"

1. Atribuindo: em outras palavras, você substitui um valor por outro `x = y` (ou seja, se **X** é igual 2 e **Y** é igual 1, o valor de **X** passa a ser 1)

```js
var x = 2, y = 1;
console.log(x = y); // 1
```

2. Adicionando: quando falamos de números, aqui o valor é somado `x += y` (**X** sendo igual a 2 e **Y** sendo igual a 1, o valor de **X** passa a ser 3)

```js
var x = 2, y = 1;
console.log(x += y); // 3
```

Como o problema acima envolve *String*, ou seja, Texto este operador passa a [concatená-los](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Strings#concatenando_strings), desta forma representado em [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)

```js
var texto1 = "a", texto2 = "b", texto3 = "c";

var resultado = texto1 + texto2 + texto3;
console.log(resultado); // abc
```

<sup>note que os textos estão armazenados em 3 variáveis diferentes!</sup>

---

#### Portanto, para acrescentar sem substituir o valor/texto anterior basta utilizar o operador `+=`

```js
var textarea = document.querySelector('textarea');
textarea.value += "21"; // value pois trata-se de uma entrada, diferente de um parágrafo <p>texto</p> (que entra o innerText())
```

```html
<textarea>Minha idade é: </textarea>
```

veja que o texto pré-definido "Minha idade é: " é mantido após acrescentar o "21" e não substituído!

---

#### Fiz um pequeno código onde traz uma possível solução baseado na sua pergunta!

Pois nela está faltando os critérios de [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) é de extrema importância dar uma lida para assim, elaborar uma boa pergunta.

```js
const textarea = document.querySelector('textarea'); // referencia da textarea
const p = document.querySelector('p'); // referencia do parágrafo

// dispara o evento ao ser pressionada as teclas
textarea.addEventListener('keypress', event => {
  console.log(event.key); // imprime a letra, simbolo e/ou número correspondente a tecla pressionada dentro do textarea.
  p.innerText += event.key;
});
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
<p></p>
```

Comment: @AugustoVasques ah sim! maravilha! fiz as devidas correções nos trechos de código.. Mas, qual foi o real objetivo? ou necessidade? no site diz que *"O objetivo dessas novas regras adicionais é fazer com que os usuários cujos layouts de teclado mapeiam caracteres Unicode para teclas de pontuação em um layout de teclado dos EUA possam usar aplicativos da web que suportam Firefox apenas com layouts de teclado compatíveis com ASCII ou apenas com um layout de teclado dos EUA. Caso contrário, os valores mapeados recentemente podem entrar em conflito com outras chaves."* em tradução livre.

Comment: @AugustoVasques não entendi bem o propósito, mas tudo bem!

Comment: É que não existe apenas um padrão de teclado. Aqui no Brazil o comum é o padrão QWERTY, mas em outros países também há QWERTZ, QWERTK,..... e o keycode não consegue distinguir entre esses padrões havendo a possibilidade de dum mapeamento equivocado do teclado, por isso o depreciamento.

Comment: @AugustoVasques ah sim, então quem é responsável por distinguir esse padrão é o próprio browser certo!? obrigado pela definição..

Comment: Concatenar sempre no final tem outros problemas. Por exemplo, digite "abc", depois volte o cursor para o início da linha e digite "d". O conteúdo do textarea será "dabc", mas no parágrafo ficará "abcd". Talvez seja mais simples pegar todo o conteúdo do textarea e jogar de uma vez no parágrafo. Lembrando também que usar `innerText` em vez de `innerHTML`  pode dar diferença: https://jsfiddle.net/y84xhaju/

Comment: @hkotsubo sim, sim! como o autor não definiu essa questão na pergunta, ou seja, baseado no código dele `paragrafo.innerHTML = event.keyCode;` creio que a intenção e desejo dele é obter a tecla e armazená-la na tag <p> (*não entendi bem o propósito, mas faria desta forma que você mencionou também*)